# PHP TMDb API - How work with search results using php-tmdb API wrapper?

Tags: php, themoviedb-api

I am using this: https://github.com/php-tmdb/api - a PHP wrapper for TMDb API. It seems really good, and there are loads of examples to work from. But I am completely stuck getting started with it.

I need to run a search on the API and parse the result. Simple right? But I cannot find any methods or means for working with the returned search object.

The API wrapper provides two ways to use the API, the preferred way is using the Model API.

Here is what I have got so far (based on the examples provided):

```
$token  = new \Tmdb\ApiToken(TMDB_API_KEY);
$client = new \Tmdb\Client($token);

$search = new \Tmdb\Repository\SearchRepository($client);
$query = new \Tmdb\Model\Search\SearchQuery\TvSearchQuery();
$query->page($page);


print_r($search->searchTv('breaking bad', $query));
```

This works fine and I get a result. However, the result is an object, and all of it's properties are either protected or private. So I have no idea how to access the result and work with it. Here's an example of the result:

```
Tmdb\Model\Collection\ResultCollection Object
(
    [page:Tmdb\Model\Collection\ResultCollection:private] => 1
    [totalPages:Tmdb\Model\Collection\ResultCollection:private] => 1
    [totalResults:Tmdb\Model\Collection\ResultCollection:private] => 1
    [data:protected] => Array
        (
            [0000000078e3674f0000000033ed0f6b] => Tmdb\Model\Tv Object
                (
                    [backdropPath:Tmdb\Model\Tv:private] => /bzoZjhbpriBT2N5kwgK0weUfVOX.jpg
                    [createdBy:Tmdb\Model\Tv:private] => 
                    [contentRatings:Tmdb\Model\Tv:private] => Tmdb\Model\Common\GenericCollection Object
                        (
                            [data:protected] => Array
                                (
                                )

                        )

                    [episodeRunTime:Tmdb\Model\Tv:private] => 
                    [firstAirDate:Tmdb\Model\Tv:private] => DateTime Object
                        (
                            [date] => 2008-01-19 00:00:00.000000
                            [timezone_type] => 3
                            [timezone] => UTC
                        )

                    [genres:Tmdb\Model\Tv:private] => Tmdb\Model\Collection\Genres Object
                        (
                            [data:protected] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Tmdb\Model\Genre Object
                                        (
                                            [id:Tmdb\Model\Genre:private] => 18
                                            [name:Tmdb\Model\Genre:private] => 
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                    [homepage:Tmdb\Model\Tv:private] => 
                    [id:Tmdb\Model\Tv:private] => 1396
                    [inProduction:Tmdb\Model\Tv:private] => 
                    [languages:Tmdb\Model\Tv:private] => 
                    [lastAirDate:Tmdb\Model\Tv:private] => 
                    [name:Tmdb\Model\Tv:private] => Breaking Bad
```

I can't see anything in the documentation and have been getting nowhere fast for a couple of hours now.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably forgetting that you are dealing with a Collection of items, instead of a single result being returned from your query.

That said, the following edited example should guide you to the rest :)

```
$token  = new \Tmdb\ApiToken(TMDB_API_KEY);
$client = new \Tmdb\Client($token);

$token  = new \Tmdb\ApiToken(TMDB_API_KEY);
$client = new \Tmdb\Client($token);

$search = new \Tmdb\Repository\SearchRepository($client);
$query = new \Tmdb\Model\Search\SearchQuery\TvSearchQuery();
$query->page(1);


foreach($search->searchTv('breaking bad', $query) as $tvShow)
{
    var_dump($tvShow->getId());
}
```